# Need a regular expression for field which should allow special characters, alphanumeric characters, and spaces

Tags: java, regex, sequence, match

I am using the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-#.()/%&\\s]{0,19}.
```

The requirement for the field is it should allow any thing and the field size should be 19. 
Let me know if any corrections.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define "special characters" ...

Comment: Define each of your terms, or you will not get a correct answer.

Comment: I didn't understand if my question doesn't make any sense or do I have to give more info..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to escape the special characters. Try:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-#\.\(\)\/%&\s]{0,19}
```

You can test your regular expressions on http://rubular.com/

Comment: +1 You're essentially right. My only comment is that, depending on the Regex engine being used, certain special characters don't need to be escaped. For example, some engines don't need `-` to be escaped if they're used just after a range because the engine can figure out that the 2nd `-` couldn't be part of another range. Still, when in doubt, escaping is safe.

Comment: I am using hibernate validator

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the dash `-` or put it at the begining or at the end of the character class:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\-#.()/%&\\s]{0,19}
```

or

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9#.()/%&\\s]{0,19}
```

or

```
[a-zA-Z0-9#.()/%&\\s-]{0,19}
```

Comment: JSLint doesn't like when you don't escape your hyphens. One escape character won't kill you for consistency's sake.

Comment: `echo Hello | egrep '[a-zA-Z0-9\-#.()/%&\\s]{0,19}'` returns `egrep: Invalid range end`.

Comment: @antisanity: You're certainly right for JSLint, but OP didn't tell what language he is using.

Comment: @M42 oh, look at that. I failed to look at the tags. On top of that the syntax isn't js either. :P

Comment: so you want we use something like this [a-zA-Z0-9\\-#.()/%&\\s]{0,19}  or any corrections. This is not allowing Special characters like !@$....

Comment: @user1078081: Just add all the "special char" you want in the character class.

Comment: ok but instead adding all the special chars is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is incorrect in at least one way - if you're considering a hyphen to be a "special character", then you should put it at the beginning or end of the range.  So:  `[a-zA-Z0-9#.()/%&\s-]{0,19}`.

Characters that are "special" within the context of the regex itself are often not parsed if they're inside a range.  So you're fine with `.`, `(` and `)`.  But check your parser to make sure that it understands what `\s` means.  It might be simpler just to put a space.

Also, if your regex parser tends to delimit the regex with slashes, then you may have to escape the slash in the middle of the range: `[a-zA-Z0-9#.()\/%&\s-]{0,19}`.